# App crashes: IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to follow a tutorial from a book. I'm about 200 pages in on a 500 pages book and everything was running fine until one day, I get an error message saying "Unfortunately the "app" has stopped". I do not want to start all over again and have tried solutions on this forum to see if I can get an answer, such as going to Windows - Preferences - Android - DDMS - ticking ADHOST, restarting Eclipse and closing down ADT etc, but none seems to resolve this. 
From what I gather, this error is unique to each application and I should post the logs from logcat on the forum so that others cleverer than me can analyse it.

The following are the results from logcat:

```
01-09 18:59:22.559: I/ActivityManager(316): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.androiddevbook.onyourbike.chapter3/.MainActivity} from pid 1896
01-09 18:59:22.591: W/WindowManager(316): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21005
01-09 18:59:22.639: D/AndroidRuntime(1896): Shutting down VM
01-09 18:59:22.669: D/dalvikvm(1896): GC_CONCURRENT freed 96K, 17% free 500K/600K, paused 1ms+4ms, total 22ms
01-09 18:59:22.669: D/jdwp(1896): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
01-09 18:59:22.669: D/dalvikvm(1896): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-09 18:59:22.709: D/dalvikvm(1906): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
01-09 18:59:22.709: I/ActivityManager(316): Start proc com.androiddevbook.onyourbike.chapter3 for activity com.androiddevbook.onyourbike.chapter3/.MainActivity: pid=1906 uid=10051 gids={50051, 1028}
01-09 18:59:23.039: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
01-09 18:59:23.349: E/Trace(1906): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-09 18:59:23.779: I/Choreographer(687): Skipped 100 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-09 18:59:24.280: D/dalvikvm(1906): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 67K, 8% free 2500K/2692K, paused 40ms, total 42ms
01-09 18:59:24.299: I/dalvikvm-heap(1906): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.024MB for 1536016-byte allocation
01-09 18:59:24.429: D/dalvikvm(1906): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3998K/4196K, paused 126ms, total 126ms
01-09 18:59:24.529: D/dalvikvm(1906): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3998K/4196K, paused 5ms+25ms, total 91ms
01-09 18:59:24.629: D/dalvikvm(1906): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 3997K/4196K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
01-09 18:59:24.660: I/dalvikvm-heap(1906): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.318MB for 3456016-byte allocation
01-09 18:59:24.739: D/dalvikvm(1906): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 3% free 7372K/7572K, paused 21ms+5ms, total 78ms
01-09 18:59:24.970: D/AndroidRuntime(1906): Shutting down VM
01-09 18:59:24.970: W/dalvikvm(1906): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
**01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906): FATAL EXCEPTION: main**
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1531)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:343)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:363)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-09 18:59:24.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 18:59:24.999: W/ActivityManager(316):   Force finishing activity com.androiddevbook.onyourbike.chapter3/.MainActivity
01-09 18:59:25.009: W/WindowManager(316): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21010
01-09 18:59:25.249: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
01-09 18:59:25.540: W/ActivityManager(316): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40d01bd0 u0 com.androiddevbook.onyourbike.chapter3/.MainActivity}
01-09 18:59:25.839: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
01-09 18:59:26.089: I/Choreographer(687): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Can anyone help me please?

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androiddevbook.onyourbike.chapter3"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/helloworldicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
          <activity
            android:name="com.androiddevbook.onyourbike.chapter3.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

            <activity 
                android:name="com.androiddevbook.onyourbike.chapter3.NewPlanet" android:label="@string/activity_title_new_planet"/>

            <activity
                android:name="com.androiddevbook.onyourbike.chapter3.ConfigPlanet" android:label="@string/activity_title_configure_planet"/>

               <activity
                android:name="com.androiddevbook.onyourbike.chapter3.TravelPlanet" android:label="@string/activity_title_travel_planet"/>  

                   <activity
                android:name="com.androiddevbook.onyourbike.chapter3.AttackPlanet" android:label="@string/activity_title_attack_planet"/> 

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I figured out which xml it relates to. The xml data for which the circular dependencies error arose is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/galaxy"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:text="@string/planet_name_label" android:textColor="#FFDDAA" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_mass_label" android:textColor="#FFDDAA"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dataView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dataView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_mass_label" android:textColor="#FFFF99" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_gravity_label" android:textColor="#FFDDAA"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dataView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dataView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_gravity_label" android:textColor="#FFFF99"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_colonies_label" android:textColor="#FFDDAA"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dataView4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dataView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_colonies_label" android:textColor="#FFFF99"/>

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_population_label" android:textColor="#FFDDAA"/>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dataView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dataView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_population_label" android:textColor="#FFFF99"/>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_military_label" android:textColor="#FFDDAA"/>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dataView6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dataView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_military_label" android:textColor="#FFFF99"/>

         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_bases_label" android:textColor="#FFDDAA"/>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dataView7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dataView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_bases_label" android:textColor="#FFFF99"/>

          <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_forcefield_label" android:textColor="#FFDDAA"/>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dataView8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dataView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dataView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/planet_forcefield_label" android:textColor="#FFFF99"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageEarth"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"

    android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_earth"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/earth" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dataView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dataView7"
    android:text="@string/planet_name_label"
    android:textColor="#FFFF99" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout` - post your layout XML please.

Comment: Look for two or more layout views that are dependant on each other. You cant say "a is to right to b" and "b is to left to a". That is circular dependency.

Comment: I suggest having a look at a free version of source control so that it's easy to roll-back to a previous well-known state when things like this happen. http://stackoverflow.com/a/976175/3063884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are trying to have two columns, text | data. I move the dataView1 code below the textView1 for the sake of pattern and put toRightOf=textView1 and took out the "alignLeft" and "above".

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/dataView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
android:text="string/planet_name_label"
android:textColor="#FFFF99" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried to find where the circular dependency exists....I stopp because your code gave me a headache.  Maybe you could change your xml ID names from TextView1, TextView2, TextView3, etc. and DataView1, Dataview2, Dataview3, etc to something meaningful?

Comment: LOL. Thats how the book wanted it done:) i found the circular exception. It was in the last textview box for dataView1. It referred back textView8 and dataView7 incorrectly causing a circular dependency.